# Apache 2.4 apachebuddy.pl

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I am trying to tune Apache2.4.6 on CentOS 7 using apachebuddy.pl.

I type the following:

> sudo perl apachebuddy.pl

and get the following result.

> Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at apachebuddy.pl
>   line 125 (#1)
>       (W newline) A file operation was attempted on a filename, and that
>       operation failed, PROBABLY because the filename contained a newline,
>       PROBABLY because you forgot to chomp() it off.  See "chomp" in perlfunc.

Not sure how to fix it. I google it and could not find a solution.

Does anyone have any advice.

Comment: Can you post line 125 from the version you're using and maybe some neighboring lines for context as well.

Comment: I downloaded the file from the following.  Please have a look.  https://raw.github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl/master/apachebuddy.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to check apachebuddy.pl issues : https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl/issues/17

It seems your trouble as been fix in last branch since may.

As it is an open source project, if you problem still occur even if you updated your version, you may have to post on Github issue to warn the author about this trouble, he will be the best to help you and fix his code.